# What options are there for migrating sqlite databases when upgrading OS apps?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios, migration

Essentially I want to migrate sqlite schemata, and data accordingly, as I upgrade iPhone applications. I've heard of migrations frameworks becoming more popular in the Ruby, Java and .NET spaces, but is there something to help me in the iOS space?

CoreData isn't an option for me at the moment. (Please don't ask why, it just isn't.)

If a migrations library isn't available what approaches do you take?

Answer (score 1):

In my past I usually kept a version info using a PRAGMA command in the database. Whenever my app starts up, I check which version the database is currently in, and call any needed update routines to alter the structure.

For most cases having a whole framework to do that is overkill; especially if you have less than 10 or 20 tables in the database.

Some pseudocode:

```
currentVersion = getCurrentDbVersion()

if currentVersion < 2 then
  upgradeToVersion2();
end if

if currentVersion < 3 then
  upgradeToVersion3();
end if

if currentVersion < 4 then
  upgradeToVersion4();
end if
```

Here is some more information about that PRAGMA command:
http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: When I had to do this, I used an array of versions and update statements; the code iterates the code and runs the update statements for each version if the database is older (the last one of which is e.g. `PRAGMA user_version = 1`). It seems to work okay. The previous "solution" was just to execute all update statements, with the assumption that we'd only ever add tables/columns so re-applying old updates would fail harmlessly.